# Why isn’t $\rm H_2 O$ a primordial element?

Tags: cosmology, water, big-bang, molecules

We’re told the universe was very hot and energetic immediately after the [Big Bang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang), and just shows H<sub>2</sub>O was present early on. Yet, it is not considered to be a primordial element. Why is that?, and what theories might suggest that H<sub>2</sub>O formed from Big Bang nucleosynthesis?

Comment: Who tells this? A search for primordial water leads down a rabbit hole.

Comment: How long is, "immediately after?" I did not think you could have oxygen before you had at least one generation of stars. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen#Isotopes_and_stellar_origin

Comment: All chemical elements (Z>1) are produced by nucleosynthesis in stars: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_nucleosynthesis

Comment: $\rm H_2 O$ is a molecule

Comment: @TheTiler I think it is valid for elements $Z>3$. H, He and Li are created in Big Bang nucleosynthesis.

Comment: @jim: You have to make the wheel before designing where it is going to be.

Comment: "In 1939, in a Nobel lecture entitled "Energy Production in Stars", Hans Bethe analyzed the different possibilities for reactions by which hydrogen is fused into helium.[10] He defined two processes that he believed to be the sources of energy in stars. "wikepedia

Comment: It isn’t primordial and it isn’t an element?

Comment: There are two ways of producing it: Big Bang nucleosynthesis,Nucleosynthesis in stars , like any production method that evolves.if I put z>3 it means that all the helium is produced at the beginning...

Answer (score 12):

The only chemical elements created in during the Big Bang are hydrogen (H), helium (He) and lithium (Li). This phenomenon is called [Big Bang nucleosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang_nucleosynthesis) and current theories predict very well the abundance of these elements. Heavier elements were not produced during the Big Bang and if they were produced it was such a tiny amount that it is negligible.

To get oxygen one had to wait (hundred million years) to the formation of stars and the production of heavier elements, in what is called [stellar nucleosynthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_nucleosynthesis). Early stars burn H, after all H is burnt, the stars burn He, and it is only after the star is old enough (after billions of years or less, depending on the mass) that these stars can produce oxygen (O) through the [carbon-nitrogen-oxygen (CNO) cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNO_cycle).

Water is not a chemical element, it is a molecule H<sub>2</sub>O, for water to form you need both H and O. For that you have to wait (billions of years) for these old stars to go supernova and release all these elements. After a while (billions of years), some elements will fuse creating icy rocks and early proto-planets where water can be found.

So no, it is not "primordial", in the sense that it not formed in the "very early" stages (Big Bang) of the universe history.

Comment: The very earliest stars (probably) had lifespans much shorter than a billion years because they were so large. Our theories about these stars are currently rather tentative, and we don't yet have any confirmed direct observations of them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_population#Population_III_stars

Comment: Theories about very early stars may be tentative, but it's well attested that many [modern stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_evolution) have / had lifespans much shorter than a billion years.